# Pool results of 5 Amelia imputed datasets after NLME growth modelling

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, data-imputation, growth-model

I have a longitudinal data set and I used Amelia to create 5 imputed sets. Then I use the `NLME` package in `R` to do growth modelling on each of the imputed data sets separately. I am looking for a feasible way to pool the results together for reporting (including, coefficients, variance decomposition, and model comparison).